# Scraping dataTable with rvest by id, doesn't find table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from the datatable here, calling by xpath's `id`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2018"  

h <- url %>% read_html() 

h %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='qs-rankings-indicators']") %>% html_table()
```

The last command gives me this error:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

What I'm I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That table is rendered by javascript. Perhaps just get the JSON data directly from the source. Try something like this

```
tstamp <- function() as.character(trunc(as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1e3))
url <- "https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/qs-rankings-data/357051.txt"

res <- 
  jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0(url, "?_=", tstamp()))$data[, c(
    "rank_display", "score", "title", "country", "region"
  )]
```

Output

```
> head(res)
  rank_display score                                        title        country        region
1            1   100  Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT)  United States North America
2            2  98.7                          Stanford University  United States North America
3            3  98.4                           Harvard University  United States North America
4            4  97.7 California Institute of Technology (Caltech)  United States North America
5            5  95.6                      University of Cambridge United Kingdom        Europe
6            6  95.3                         University of Oxford United Kingdom        Europe
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me a bit more about "That table is rendered by javascript". How is it difficult for rvest?

Comment: Nice solution. @Damandeep rvest will load the initial HTML, but it won't run javascript. A good example of javascript loading data is a sports site that changes the score without you having to load the page (rvest won't know anything about the updated score because it's loaded via javascript *after* the initial HTML page load). Same thing happens here with the data inside the table

Comment: How can you tell a table or content is rendered by javascript? How did you get to find the url of the json data?

Comment: You can inspect network activities using a modern browser, such as Chrome. See [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) for a detailed tutorial. Basically, you just go to that webpage, right-click, choose inspect, choose network, refresh the page, and select [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) filter. Then you can see the URL of json data. @DavidJorquera

Comment: You can check the html source page to see whether the table is rendered by JS or not. The HTML source page can be retrieved by inspecting network activities. @DavidJorquera

Answer (score 2):

You actually already had it with just

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/world-university-rankings/2018"  

h <- url %>% read_html() 

h %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='qs-rankings-indicators']")

{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <table id="qs-rankings-indicators" class="order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

i.e. without the last `%>% html_table()`

The reason there's no data inside the table is because it's loaded with javascript after the initial HTML page load.

To get the table *including the javascript loaded content*, you'll need to use a scraping tool that can run the website's javascript (I would recommend [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium))